# Fake Foam Colour!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

On the side of my cup, the colour of the **foam** (as seen through glass) is much **darker** than at the top of the liquid. I have set a little rough glass material to make the glass appear frosted, but this shouldn't cause the side to be darker than the top. Since it's a glass, the colour should be uniform all around! See the image:

[image]

Notice the side of the cup (just above the black coffee) where the brown foam seems way too darker than the top. Is it an expected behaviour? Let me know if something can be done to fix this.

Comment: Is it a modelling defect of the liquid, or has something to do with UVs and materials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's accurate lighting.  In addition to your spotlight "Light" object, you are lighting the scene with a built-in Studio Lighting image, namely "forest.exr".  This has a lot of overhead lighting which hits the top of the foam directly, making it appear a significantly lighter color than the sides.  Here's a stock photo I found with similar lighting:

[image]

If you'd like to see your scene lit differently...

First, disable the studio lighting.  Make sure that "Rendered" viewport shading is selected, and to the right of the "Rendered" icon, use the pull-down to turn on the "Scene World" checkbox to switch the studio lighting to your configured world lighting (ambient light blue).  Here's a screenshot with "Scene World" unchecked.  You want to check that box:

[image]

Second, take your point light source and move it from above the scene to just behind the camera.  The result will look something like this, with virtually no color difference between the top and side of the foam:

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks.